# Single byte (\xd0) gets printed as sequence of two bytes (\xc3\x90) in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print the byte `d0` to stdout in Python 3.7.2. I have the following code:

```
print("\xd0", end = "")
```

However, when I execute this, it outputs the bytes `c390`.

```
$ python -c 'print("\xd0", end = "")' | xxd    
00000000: c3 90
```

Why is it not outputting the byte `\xd0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"\xd0"` is an `str` object, which in Python 3 is a *Unicode* string (= a sequence of Unicode *code points*) containing the Unicode *code point* U+00D0 (i.e. 208 i.e. Ð); when writing it with `print`, Python has to convert it from Unicode (`str`) to bytes (`bytes`), so it has to use an *encoding* (an "abstract codepoints" to bytes converter).

In your case, as often, it happens to be UTF-8, where codepoint U+00D0 is encoded as the code-units (= bytes) sequence c3 90.

If you want to output literally a byte 0xd0, you have to use a byte string and go straight to the bytes stream that is beyond `sys.stdout`:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\xd0')
```

Comment: Oh man, this makes so much sense. This issue cost me several hours of confusion other times where I didn't narrow it down to Python. Thank you very much. Is there something more general I can name this question since this doesn't only apply to the `d0` byte that you can think of?

Comment: @Arin: glad it helped! :-) As for the question title, I wouldn't know, maybe "single character (`\xd0`) gets printed as sequence of two characters (`\xc3\x90`)" or something like this?

Answer (score 1):

It’s printing the character U+00D0 (“Ð”) as UTF-8. If you want to output a byte string to stdout, use `sys.stdout.buffer`:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"\xd0")
```

`"\xd0"` is a string of Unicode codepoints, but `b"\xd0"` is a string of bytes.